# Can I export an elementor template to html?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, elementor

I've got a page template that I've built using elementor on wordpress. I need to add a handful of custom fields and not only do I have to upgrade to do this (really can't be bothered messing around with the licences between the dev & live sites) it seems massively over complicated & bloaty for something that should just be a template for a custom post type with 2x ACF text fields.

Right-click & save as gives me 113Kb of html that gives you a migraine at a glance. No way I'm sorting through all that.
What's the best way of doing that in your opinions?

Answer (score 1):

If your fields are text-based, and you're just looking to add the custom fields to the template, maybe you could call them via the ACF shortcode? [acf field=""]

Here the link: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/shortcode/

Answer (score 0):

As for converting Elementor templates specifically to HTML, I'm sure; but if you want to convert your WordPress website to HTML, then you could make use of the: [Simply Static WP Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simply-static/)

I hope this helps.